# MarkLogic: pass Map-Object from Java to XQuery

Tags: java, xquery, marklogic

I would like to pass a simple Java `Map<String, String>` through the MarkLogic Java API to an XQuery script. The script is already deployed to the `/ext` directory on the server and starts like this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare variable $dr as xs:string external;
declare variable $en as xs:string external;
declare variable $fi as map:map external;
...
```

I'm using the pattern described on the MarkLogic Site: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_70532 ("Basic Steps for Module Invocation").

My Java code looks like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");

ServerEvaluationCall invoker = client.newServerEval();
invoker.addVariable("dr", "foo");
invoker.addVariable("en", "bar");
invoker.addVariableAs("fi", map);
String response = invoker.evalAs(String.class);
```

This fails with this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No factory for class java.util.HashMap
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.HandleFactoryRegistryImpl.makeHandle(HandleFactoryRegistryImpl.java:98) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.ServerEvaluationCallImpl.addVariableAs(ServerEvaluationCallImpl.java:123) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.0.3.jar:?]
```

I think I need to convert the map before sending it to ML or maybe use one of the handler classes, but I was not able to solve it or find any examples of this. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work to pass a Jackson JSON object to an XQuery external variable. The value in XQuery should be either an XQuery map or a JSON node.  If it's a JSON node, the [`xdmp:from-json()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:from-json) function can convert the value to an XQuery map.

For the Java part, look for the example introduced as "the following code uses a Jackson object mapper to set an external variable value to a JSON object":

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_21827

Hoping that helps,

Comment: That really helps. I just serialize the map in Java via Jackson and deserialize it in Xquery via `xdmp:from-json-string`. Works like a charm, thanks a lot!